# Spectrum Analyzer problem

Tags: rf, noise, spectrum-analyzer, spectrum

I am seeing some strange behavior with my spectrum analyzer. It is a Tektronix RSA306B.

I have put a 50 Ω termination at the input of the spectrum analyzer and I am seeing a lot of spurious frequencies.

The spectrum is configured from 5-1000 MHz, the RBW is 100 Hz.
[image]

I found this table provided by Tektronix for this S.A.
[image]

From my understanding the noise level is at around -161dBm... Is there something I do not understant?
Does someone have an idea why?

Comment: Can you share more infos on the config of the spectrum?

Comment: At -120 dBm, just above the noise floor.

Comment: @winny why is the noise floor considered -120dBm ?

Comment: Look at where the floor of the curve is. How much voltage is -120 dBm at 50 ohm?

Comment: How are you connecting the 50 ohm termination

Comment: What are you using for the 50 ohm resistor?

Comment: it’s a termination that came with the S.A., it’s a N type termination

Comment: @DimitarZhekov If you are testing the unit with a recommended (and provided) termination and if you feel it is noisier than it should be (the temperature is in the range they specify but the noise is higher than the worst case spec), then contact Tektronix about it. I left Tek, summer of 1983, to start a business. Tek has since gone private (board of directors were not self-confident and squandered much -- I spent a day walking and talking with board member Jim Castles, late 1983, tearing his heart out.) But I have to believe they still have good people there who will want to help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to get in touch with them @periblepsis

Comment: Obligatory link to a solid reference about noise measurement: [Agilent application note 1303](https://www.ab4oj.com/test/docs/5966-4008E.pdf). There are a lot of subtle details to measuring noise. The short answer is to turn on the "Marker Noise" feature, which changes the necessary settings and does all the corrections for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spurs that you are seeing seem to be within spec:

[image]

I'm not sure that you have the analyzer configured correctly to measure noise (but I haven't used this device).  The noise level is what you see between the spurs

[image]

so the M4 marker at about -132dBm is representative.  Allowing for the 100Hz RBW, the noise bandwidth is at least 100Hz (it will be in the manual),  so this would correspond to a noise floor less than -152dBm/Hz - we're getting close to the -161dBm/Hz.

Now, this is about 10dB high, roughly what would be measured if you were using the peak detector instead of the average one, and when I see at the top of your screenshot:

[image]

this makes me suspect you have the peak detector selected.  I am not familiar with this particular spectrum analyzer,  but you should read the manual about how to make noise measurements.

You may be able to configure the marker to display noise (in dBm/Hz) which, I would assume, will configure the rest of the settings appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The spurious you are talking about are at -120 dBm. It is not a lot of energy. At those level many thing can have an impact. According to Tek, it should be able to go lower then that, but I don't know what measurement you are making for requiring a noise floor lower then 120 dBm!

Your termination might be the issue. If it's not of a great quality, you might have some small frequency component get in. If you are using any cable, they could be the culprit too.

The setting of the SA have a lot to do with the noise floor too. You might change your IF bandwidth and it will change.

Since this is a USB unit, it might be an issue of grounding. I never used those units and don't know how they are designed but I had similar issue using other test equipment that showed noise when plugged to a computer.

At those level, anything in your setup and unit will be significant. So unless it is a real issue, I wouldn't investigate too much.

Comment: Poorly designed USB cables can wreak havoc in an RF environment. Often, the cable shield connection is poorly connected to the connector ground which causes the cable to radiate. It takes going through a lot of cables to find ones that are suitable for an RF environment. I believe my colleague found that *Cable Matters* produces the least problematic cables after testing a bunch of different manufacturers cables.